# Power BI convert text mm:ss to time

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Convert a text from minutes:seconds to datatype time

I have a column with time (running time) in format (h:)mm:ss
how can i convert this to a datatype "time"  because given functions always expect the hours which i most of the time not have.

i've tried duration.FromText but the input format doesnot apply. Nor the automatic Time parse... it fails on the mm:ss part.
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Parse", each Time.From(DateTimeZone.From([Tijd])), type time)
gives a lot of errors

Comment: Please add your sample data and expected output

Comment: if you column is hh:mm:ss then changing type to time should work fine = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type time}})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't showed how your data looks like, so I will assume each value can be one of these:

- h:mm:ss - hours, minutes and seconds, where mm and ss are between 0 and 59, with a leading zeros for the single digit values (e.g. 1:01:05);
- m:ss - minutes and seconds, where ss is between 0 and 59, with a leading zeros for the single digit values (e.g. 1:05);
- s - only seconds (e.g. 5).

In this case, one thing you can do, is to re-format the data, before changing its type. Add a custom column like this:

```
if List.Count(Text.PositionOf([Time], ":", Occurrence.All)) = 0 then
    "0:00:" & Text.End("0" & [Time], 2)
else if List.Count(Text.PositionOf([Time], ":", Occurrence.All)) = 1 then
    "0:" & Text.End("0" & [Time], 5)
else
    [Time]
```

which will count how many times `:` occurs in the input string (using [Text.PositionOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-positionof) and [List.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-count)), and add suitable prefix (taking care for the leading zeroes with [Text.End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-end)):

[image]

Now you can change the data type of the newly added column to `Duration` or `Time`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. my input was indeed diverse, most of the time in format mm:ss, but your code helps!